# Failed to get server protocol; no such resource on this server

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, sesame, linked-data

I am trying to run the following query on Sesame:

```
PREFIX dbp-ontology: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/owl/>
PREFIX dbpedia-prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

select ?country ?capital
where{
  SERVICE <http://factforge.net/sparql>{
    ?country a  dbp-ontology:Country .
    ?country dbpedia-prop:capital ?capital .
  }
} LIMIT 100
```

The query gets successfully executed on one computer where I have Sesame installed. On another computer, Sesame reports the following error:

```
Query evaluation error: org.openrdf.query.QueryEvaluationException: Failed to get server protocol; no such resource on this server: http://factforge.net/sparql?queryLn=SPARQL&query=PREFIX+dbp-ontology%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E+PREFIX+rdf%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E+PREFIX+dbpedia-owl%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fowl%2F%3E+PREFIX+dbpedia-prop%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E+PREFIX+rdfs%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E+PREFIX+sesame%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.openrdf.org%2Fschema%2Fsesame%23%3E+PREFIX+owl%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23%3E+PREFIX+xsd%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%3E+PREFIX+fn%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2005%2Fxpath-functions%23%3E+SELECT++%3Fcountry+WHERE+%7B+%3Fcountry+a+dbp-ontology%3ACountry+.+%7D&infer=true
```

What is causing this? How can it be resolved? The hyperlink above actually displays the results of the query in a browser.

UPDATE: All this is for the computer where the connection with FactForge cannot be established:

1. I am using 2.7.16
2. Executing the query via the workbench
3. Following is from the log file named tomcat8-stderr:

31-Jul-2015 15:15:37.717 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.openrdf.http.client.HTTPClient.getErrorInfo Server reports problem: Query evaluation error: org.openrdf.query.QueryEvaluationException:
31-Jul-2015 15:15:37.718 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.openrdf.workbench.commands.QueryServlet.handleStandardBrowserRequest org.openrdf.repository.http.HTTPQueryEvaluationException: Query evaluation error: org.openrdf.query.QueryEvaluationException:
 org.openrdf.repository.http.HTTPQueryEvaluationException: Query evaluation error: org.openrdf.query.QueryEvaluationException:
    at org.openrdf.repository.http.HTTPTupleQuery.evaluate(HTTPTupleQuery.java:59)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.util.QueryEvaluator.evaluateTupleQuery(QueryEvaluator.java:152)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.util.QueryEvaluator.evaluate(QueryEvaluator.java:287)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.util.QueryEvaluator.extractQueryAndEvaluate(QueryEvaluator.java:120)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.commands.QueryServlet.service(QueryServlet.java:382)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.commands.QueryServlet.handleStandardBrowserRequest(QueryServlet.java:216)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.commands.QueryServlet.service(QueryServlet.java:206)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.base.TransformationServlet.service(TransformationServlet.java:109)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.commands.QueryServlet.service(QueryServlet.java:163)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.base.BaseServlet.service(BaseServlet.java:142)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.ProxyRepositoryServlet.service(ProxyRepositoryServlet.java:104)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.WorkbenchServlet.service(WorkbenchServlet.java:222)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.WorkbenchServlet.handleRequest(WorkbenchServlet.java:151)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.WorkbenchServlet.service(WorkbenchServlet.java:119)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.WorkbenchGateway.service(WorkbenchGateway.java:131)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.base.BaseServlet.service(BaseServlet.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.CacheFilter.doFilter(CacheFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.CookieCacheControlFilter.doFilter(CookieCacheControlFilter.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.openrdf.repository.RepositoryException: Query evaluation error: org.openrdf.query.QueryEvaluationException:
    at org.openrdf.http.client.HTTPClient.handleHTTPError(HTTPClient.java:953)
    at org.openrdf.http.client.HTTPClient.sendTupleQueryViaHttp(HTTPClient.java:718)
    at org.openrdf.http.client.HTTPClient.getBackgroundTupleQueryResult(HTTPClient.java:602)
    at org.openrdf.http.client.HTTPClient.sendTupleQuery(HTTPClient.java:367)
    at org.openrdf.repository.http.HTTPTupleQuery.evaluate(HTTPTupleQuery.java:53)
    ... 42 more

4. This is a repeatable issue
5. There are two differences between the computers:

Functional Sesame Computer - Windows 8, The folder path where Sesame data is stored is visible in the 'About' page

Sub-functional Sesame Computer -  Windows 7. Folder path is not mentioned.

Comment: 1. Which version of Sesame are you using? 2. How are you executing this query (programmatically or via the Workbench)? 3. Is there anything more to the error message (e.g. a stacktrace) or anything more in the logs? 4. Is this repeatable or a one-time glitch? 5. Are there any obvious differences between the two computers apart from the fact that one reports this error and the other does not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by reinstalling everything starting from jre. There were two versions of jre on the computer and I guess reinstalling just one after removing the previous ones did the trick. Along with jre (i.e., as a component of the Java SE package), I also reinstalled Tomcat and Sesame.